# Configure shell cursor to blink

Tags: bash

What configuration is required to have the terminal cursor blink? Mine does not blink. Please advise.

The system is macOS 10.14 running bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The appearance of the terminal under macOS can be customized in Terminal Preferences (Command+, when in Terminal.app). There’s a blink cursor checkbox at the bottom of the first tab in this window.